# Web API - How to dispose an SQL connection correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, sqlconnection

I have a simple Web API controller:

```
public class CarsController : ApiController
{        
    public SqlConnection Db { get; set; }

    public CarsController()
    {            
        Db = new SqlConnection("XXX");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetAll()
    {
        //Fetch cars from DB...            
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            Db.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I put the dispose code in Dipose() override because I want to **write it once**.

- Can I be sure the dispose code will be called in any situation? (Exceptions for
  example).
- Can I be sure that the controller will be disposed **right after** the
  call to the action is finished, freeing up resources to upcoming
  calls.
- If not, is there a more robust/correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

By using `Dispose()`you are waiting for the GC to clean up the controller. Use a `Using` statement within your `async Task` method and the object will be freed up immediately. Exception or not the sqlConnection object will be disposed of. You should instantiate the `SqlConnection` in the `async Task` instead of the constructor to effectively use the `Using`.

Comment: I don't want the Using statement because I will be forced to write it over and over again for each new action in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a dependency injection container, in order to keep control over the IDbConnection instanciation. In particular, have a look to the lifetime manager and the HierarchicalLifetimeManager.

That way you can get rid of manually managing your object disposal in a per request way.

A good start [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the approach outlined here: [Disposing resources at the end of Web API request](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/08/disposing-resources-at-the-end-of-web-api-request/).

The Web API framework provides the method HttpRequestMessage.RegisterForDispose to allow you to register any and all references you would like disposed at the end of a request. So your code would look like this:

```
public class CarsController : ApiController
{        
    public SqlConnection Db { get; set; }

    public CarsController()
    {            
        Db = new SqlConnection("XXX");
        Db.Open();
        Request.RegisterForDispose(Db);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetAll()
    {
        //Fetch cars from DB...            
    }
}
```

In my project I'm creating a base class for all my controllers where I'm initializing the DB connections and registering them for disposal. So not only will I not be writing any SqlConnection boilerplate for my actions, but also not for any controller.